# Test if object with attribute exists in an array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Can someone please tell me the best way to check if an object within an array of objects has a `type` of `11`?

Below is what I have but it will alert for every object in the array, can I check the whole array and get it to alert just the once at the end?

I've seen methods like grep but I've been trying and can't get it to work. I'm using jQuery.

```
var x;
for (x = 0; x < objects.length; x++) {

    if (objects[x].type == 11) {
        alert("exists");
    } else {
        alert("doesnt exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you're using?

Comment: @BrianCray he/she is alerting every iteration

Comment: `I've seen methods like grep but I've been trying and can't get it to work.` This is how you would use [**grep**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/): `var existGrep = jQuery.grep(objects, function(item) { return(item.type === 11); });` I only added it to show you how you get `grep()` to work but off course any of the other answers are more suitable/efficient like `Array.some` or using `break` as `grep()` will iterate through the whole array.

Answer (score 4):

Best way is use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var exists = objects.some(function(el) { return el.type === 11 });
```

In the link there is also a shim for the browser that doesn't support it.

Otherwise you can just iterate:

```
var exists = false;
for (var i = 0, el; !exists && (el = objects[i++]);)
    exists = el.type === 11;
```

Once you have the `exists` variable set, you can just do:

```
if (exists) {
    // do something
}
```

Outside the loop, in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should actually do it. If you're bothered that the *loop* will continue uselessly, you can abort it by calling `break;`

```
if(objects[x].type == 11){
    alert("exists");
    break;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it a function:

```
function hasObjWithType11(arr) {
    var x;
    for (x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        if(arr[x].type == 11){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

alert(hasObjWithType11([{type:1}, {type:11}]); // alerts true
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it

```
var exists = false;
for (var x = 0; x < objects.length; x++) {
     if(objects[x].type == 11){
       exists = true;
       break;
     }
}
if(exists){
    alert("exists");
}
```

Comment: No need for the else, it's already declared false before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the searching code more reusable by wrapping it into a separate function. That way you can externalize the condition for easier reading:

```
function array_contains(a, fn)
{
    for (i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (fn(a[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (array_contains(objects, function(item) { return item.type == 11; })) {
    alert('found');
}
```

You could also use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
if (objects.some(function(item) {
  return item.type == 11;
})) {
    alert('exists');
}
```

For IE < 9, refer to the MDN documentation for a mock version.